# How to simulate an external piece of hardware during the development of a LabView FPGA project

Tags: fpga

I am working on a PXI system from National Instruments. It has an FPGA card that I have connected externally to a sensor.

I would like to know how to perform a "cycle accurate" simulation that includes a custom external stimulus that emulates the sensor.

There is a lot of example for simulating the labView -> FPGA -> labView interfaces, but nothing for LabView -> FPGA -> external hardware.

If it hasn't been a NI FPGA system, I would have written an HDL test bench for that, but within the NI FPGA framework, I can't figure out where to put my test bench.

In fact there is a place to put an HDL test bench, but as I said, the only available interface to test is the one between the labView code and the FPGA, and not between the FPGA and the external FPGA pins.

Maybe one of you already faced that issue.

I have some ideas such as : Custom CLIP that embedded the VHDL for simulation of the interface?

I already posted on StackExchange, but only EE's play with FPGA... ;-)